# Objects are not valid as a React child getting error when adding div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am just rendering the data and display in between `divs` but I am getting error this

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Dec 09 1998
>   00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead.

```
<Fragment key={String(index) + String(i)}>
                    <div>{displaytext}</div>
                    <div>{value}</div>
                  </Fragment>
```

Only issue is on this line `<div>{value}</div>` if I remove this line everything works fine.If I add this line I am getting above error why ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/ooj2wowy9q

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`value` is a date object. Try this:

```
<div>{moment(value).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}</div>
```

Comment: @user944513 if wdm's answer solves your question, please mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 18):

React doesn't allow objects like Dates or Arrays as children, you need to convert `value` to string, like this:

```
<div>{new Date(value).toString()}</div>
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be using a date wrongly

```
<div>{value.toDateString()}</div>
```

might solve the problem

Comment: this is what works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{date.toLocaleDateString()}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date is Object itself and Objects are not valid as a React child.
You need to convert value to string as,

```
<div>{value.toDateString()}</div>
```

Or, you can use [Moment Js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
<div>{moment(value).format('DD-MM-YYYY')}</div>
```

Comment: Your answer just repeats the solutions presented in other (upvoted and even accepted) answers. Please do not posts answers unless you have something to add.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `new Date(...)` in combination with `* 1000` to get the workable date format, an example:

`new Date(props.date * 1000).toLocaleDateString()`