# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date])

Tags: reactjs, date

I'm currently developing a simple Application that allows users to upload a photo.

I'm trying to display all exif data using exif.fr

The issue at the moment is in the DateTimeOriginal object property I want to display.

I was able to display if I excluded all the date from the exif object

Below is the component of displaying exif data that I'm having problem

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../hook/Context";

export default function Modal() {
  const { uploadso, onImageChange, imgDat, data } = useContext(Context);
  const [upload, setUpload] = uploadso;
  const [img, setImgData] = imgDat;
  const [datas, setData] = data;
  const omittedProps = ["CreateDate", "ModifyDate"];

  return (
    <div>
      {!upload && (
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            multiple
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={onImageChange}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      {!upload && !img && (
        <div>
          {datas.map((each) => {
            if (datas == undefined || datas == null) {
              return;
            } else {
              return [
                Object.keys(each).map((key, index) => {
                  return (
                    !omittedProps.includes(key) && (
                      <div key={index}>
                        {key}:{each[key]}
                      </div>
                    )
                  );
                }),
              ];
            }
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is the error that shown if I don't exclude DateOfOriginal to render and I already excluded CreatedTime and ModifyDate and each date have object property

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType
```

this is the data that I'm trying to display

```
{
    "Make": "Canon",
    "Model": "Canon DIGITAL IXUS",
    "Orientation": "Horizontal (normal)",
    "ModifyDate": "2001-06-09T07:17:32.000Z",
    "YCbCrPositioning": 1,
    "ExposureTime": 0.002857142857142857,
    "FNumber": 4,
    "ExifVersion": "2.1",
    "DateTimeOriginal": "2001-06-09T07:17:32.000Z",
    "CreateDate": "2001-06-09T07:17:32.000Z",
    "CompressedBitsPerPixel": 3,
    "ShutterSpeedValue": 8.451217651367188,
      
}
```

Comment: What's the content if you log out `CreateDate`?

Comment: Show us what is `datas`

Comment: Completely unrelated, but man, `each` as a variable name is really throwing me off. `datas.map` is resolving to an array of arrays of arrays; that seems an unlikely scenario.

Comment: .and if I excluded all the date (createdDate,ModifyDate,DateTimeOriginal) I was able to render all data  @Camilo

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using momentjs from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714327/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-getting-error-when-adding-div)

```
{key}:{moment(each[key]).format("DD-MM-YYYY")}
```